# Blender error "exception_access_violation"

Tags: error

System: Windows 64-bit, 32gb RAM, Intel Core i7-9700 CPU, NVIDIA Quadro K2000 graphics card

Latest Blender doesn't open, it just gives the error message "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" I really have no idea what's going on.

I tried downgrading to 2.7 and even 2.0 but those didn't work either. I also tried the Steam version, and each time made sure there was only 1 version installed at a time.

Comment: Is it just me or are there a lot of similar questions like this all of a sudden... is there some update going around messing with peoples blender?

Comment: Hello, which version of windows are you using ?

Comment: I heard updating your driver might be a quick fix.